# WPF TabItem Element MouseClick Event

Tags: wpf, events, controls, mouseevent, tabitem

In WPF app inside a `TabControl` there is a `TabItem` element with one `Label`. I want to fire the event on `MouseClick` on the `Tab` of this `TabControl`, but the event `MouseLeftButtonDown`:

```
<TabItem Header="Header1" MouseLeftButtonDown="TabItem_MouseLeftButtonDown" >
      <Label Height="28" Name="AdderLbl" Width="120" Background="Azure" >Label</Label>
</TabItem>
```

fires only on click over the label. It is not wat I want.

How I could fire the event on `MouseClick` over the `Tab`, not its content?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It looks like you're trying to trap when the user moves to the tab, if so you can hook a different event `SelectionChanged`

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted. And it works. Thanks. I'd choose your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? It looks like you're trying to trap when the user moves to the tab, if so you can hook a different event `SelectionChanged`

:-)

Answer (score 3):

I did not want selectionchanged event because that would involve a switch. So i wanted an event directly on the tab clicked.

While i thought an MouseDown event was what I was looking for.... after wiring up all sorts of mouse events with break points; i found the MouseUp events worked for me.

So I used `MouseLeftButtonUp` or `MouseUp`.

Answer (score 1):

For who really want to use something like MouseLeftButtonDown event, you can use the "**MouseUp**" event instead.
=)

Answer (score 0):

While handling `SelectionChanged` event is the better approach to handling tab changes, here is a possible solution to your question. I don't recommend it in your case, but it illustrates an approach that may be useful in other cases

```
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <Button Click="Button_Click">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Label>Header1</Label>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </TabItem.Header>

            <Label Height="28" Name="AdderLbl" Width="120" Background="Azure" >Label</Label>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the event `Selector.Selected`

Answer (score 0):

```
<TabControl x:Name ="TabControls" Dock="Top" DockWidth="500" DockHeight="500"     TabItemShape="Rounded">
<TabControl>

 TabControls.SelectionChanged += SelectionChanged;

 private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs) {

     var itemTab = (TabItem) TabControls.SelectedItem;

    (...) 
 }
```